# WPF DataGrid MVVM Changing value of one column as user changes another column

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, datagrid, datatable

I am using DataGrid binding to DataTable.

I want do the following: 
if the value of TargetUnit column is empty, change the SelectedIndex of Combobox to 1 
otherwise change SelectedIndex to 0.

I'm doing the following:

```
                <DataGrid MaxHeight="400" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" IsEnabled="{Binding Enabled}" ItemsSource="{Binding Spread.DefaultView}" SelectedItem="{Binding SpreadSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" Width="70"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="No of Items"  Binding="{Binding Path=NoOfItems}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rename Unit"  Binding="{Binding Path=TargetUnit, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Action Type" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=ActionType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource SpreadActionTypeConverter}}">
                            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.UnitConversionActionTypes}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=TargetUnit}" Value="">
                                            <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="1"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.UnitConversionActionTypes}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=TargetUnit}" Value="">
                                            <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="1"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: Have you tried doing this in Your ViewModel? If it's binded properly it should work. Bind SelectedIndex to VM property and set in on "TargetUnit" text property change.

Comment: I'm using DataTable here. If it were observable collection/list, I could bind as the way you have mentioned. Any idea whether it is possible/ not possible for Data Table?

Comment: So create a property in Your Model (single item displayed in DataTable) and bind it as if it were a ViewModel